# Eclipse package explorer have different icons for each file type: interfaces, abstract classes, etc

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Does anyone know of an eclipse plugin that changes the file icon used by the package explorer to something that indicates type? It would be handy if the icon looked different for interfaces, abstract classes, enum, and concrete classes.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can enable a feature in Eclipse similar to what you are describing. Open Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations. Then check the box for Java Type Indicator. I do not know of any plug-ins that give you more control.